# Firestore get() fetches no data in Flask

Tags: python, firebase, flask, digital-ocean

I'm unable to get data from the firebase cloud firestore on my production server. I have the following code:

```
@app.route('/forgot-password', methods=['GET','POST'])
def forgotpassword():

    if 'email' in session:
        return redirect(url_for('profile'))

    form = ForgotPasswordForm() 
    if form.validate_on_submit():

        try:
            user_ref = db.collection(u'users').document(form.email.data)
            user = user_ref.get()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        if user.exists:
            try:
                auth.send_password_reset_email(form.email.data)
                print(form.email.data)

                flash('A link to reset your password has been sent to your mail.', 'success')
            except Exception as e:
                print(e)
                flash('There was an error while sending the email.', 'danger')      

        else:           
            print("not registerd")
            flash('This email is not registered.', 'danger')

    print(form.errors)

    return render_template('forgotPasswordPage.html', form=form)
```

I am not getting any output for the exception since none seems to be thrown. The same code works on my localhost but not on the production server.

`db.collection(u'users').document(form.email.data)` succesfully returns a firestore document object but the `get()` function is the one causing the problem. What could be the problem?

Comment: are you getting anything logged when it doesn't work? how have you determined it was the `.get()`?

Comment: Hi @SoniSol thanks for reaching out. I'm not getting any logs. The execution just stops.

Comment: what is your production server?

Comment: Its a LAMP server on Digital Ocean